# How to add scroll class to element and remove it when done

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to add a scrolling class to a text every 1 minute once the text finished scrolling i will remove the class and wait for the next 1 minute. Please can anyone help me out on this below is my sample code but it doesn't work as expected.

```js
$(function(event){
 $infoLongMessage = $("#infoLongMessage");
    var wait = 60000;
 var timer = ($infoLongMessage.text().length + wait);

 setInterval(function(){
  $infoLongMessage.toggleClass("scroll-left");
 }, timer);
 })
```

```css
.content{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  }
#infoLongMessage{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  display:block;
}


.scroll-left{
   /* Starting position */
   -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
   -webkit-transform:translateX(100%); 
   transform:translateX(100%);
   /* Apply animation to this element */ 
   -moz-animation: scrollleft 15s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: scrollleft 15s linear infinite;
   animation: scrollleft 15s linear infinite;
}
 
  
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes scrollleft {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scrollleft {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes scrollleft {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);   
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<span id="infoLongMessage" class="scroll-left">Browser sources let you display a webpage from the internet or a local file and are commonly used for widgets and alerts</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to explain your idea to us. 1. Start to scroll left from outside of the window. 2. When it reaches to left stop and wait 1 minute. 3. ?

Comment: I think you should listen to 'animationend' event and remove class, when it's fired - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

Comment: @hurricane my idea is to add the `scroll` every 1min and once the the text done scrolling remove the class and wait for another 1min

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any js to achieve your idea. You need a ticker. Also you can put delay to your animation if you need.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
.ticker-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #9a1f1f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  padding-left: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.ticker-wrap .ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
  animation-name: ticker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-duration: 30s;
}
.ticker-wrap .ticker__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker-wrap">
  <div class="ticker">
    <div class="ticker__item">Hi Lea!</div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Look at them !!!</div>
    <div class="ticker__item">Owww new items...</div>
    <div class="ticker__item">
      offers | save up to 50% — shop now
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```